# Playing Sound Without User Interaction JS

Tags: javascript, laravel

I want to create a sound notification when an event is sent. How can I prevent it from being blocked by the browser?

```js
window.userId = {{ auth()->user()->user_id }};
const channelName = `laravel_database_chat.${window.userId}`;
const messageSound = new Audio('{{ asset('clients/assets/mp3/press.wav') }}');


function playAudio() {
  messageSound.play();
}

window.Echo.channel(channelName).listen('.MessageEvent', (data) => {
  console.log(data)
  if (data.receiverId === window.userId) {
    Livewire.dispatch('chat');
    setTimeout(() => {
      playAudio();
    }, 1000);
  }
});
```

Comment: You can only play sound when the user has interacted with the page, eg. clicked a button. Any attempt to play media on load will be blocked by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the **wav** audio format, although it is compatible with most browsers, it is always a good idea to check that the error is not being caused by the audio format.

To prevent audio from being blocked, it is a good practice to add a visible audio control (an audio player) to your HTML page, even if it is hidden. This way, the browser will understand that the audio is related to a visible media element and will be less likely to block it.

Additionally, it may be useful to provide an option for the user to enable or disable sound notifications. This allows the user to have control over the audio in their application.